# Calculating the pH of a dilluted aqueous KOH solution

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

> Calculate $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}$ of an aqueous solution of $0.01\:\mathrm{nM}~\ce{KOH}$ in water.

I think that water also has $\ce{OH-}$ ions in concentration of $10^{-7}\:\mathrm{M}$ (since $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}=7$)

So the total concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ after mixing the solution with water would be:

$0.01\:\mathrm{nM} + 10^{-7}\:\mathrm{M} = 10^{-11}\:\mathrm{M} + 10^{-7}\:\mathrm{M} \implies 1.0001 \times 10^{-7}\:\mathrm{M}$

and given that $\mathrm{pH} = 14 - \mathrm{p}\ce{OH}$

$\implies 14 - \log(1.0001\times10^{-7})$

$\implies \mathrm{pH} \approx 7$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to hear! Has been some time since I had chemistry in high school and couldn't find any example on the internet. Glad that I didn't provide any false information :)

Comment: Since this is my first post here on stack chemistry, I am wondering how you guys handle questions like this. Shall I delete it, or can someone just post a "yes" answer that I accept - so that it isn't kept marked as "unanswered". (maybe someone might find this question useful as future reference, maybe it is so trivial that it isn't necessary?)

Comment: ok, I added actual answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's right, the concentration of $\ce{{}^{-}OH}$ from dissociation of water will be much greater than the amount added from $0.01\:\mathrm{nM}~\ce{KOH}$.

$0.01\:\mathrm{nM}~\ce{KOH}$ will not significantly the affect $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}$ of water.

Answer (score 3):

Your result is correct but I don't agree with your method. Your method would fail under certain circumstances. Which circumstances you might ask? When the pH of the solution is *actually* between 6.8 and 7.2. In these cases, your assumption that water auto-ionizes to create exactly $\ce{[HO^-]} = 1.0\times10^{-7} M $ will have significant figure implications).

About your assumption:

$\ce{[HO^-]} = 1.0\times10^{-7}$

This is *not* true when you add any amount of acid or base to water because the addition of either (or both) will disrupt the equilibrium that exists in water (referred to as $\ce{K_{w}}$, the auto-protolysis of water, or the auto-ionization of water):

$\ce{2H_2O <=> HO^- + H_3^+O}$

$\ce{K_{w}=[HO^-][H_3^+O]}=1.0\times10^{-14}$

*All* you know about your system is that $\ce{[HO^-]_{water} = [H_3^+O]_{water}}$. This is in fact true for *any* water solution; as we can see from the auto-ionization reaction above, there exists a 1:1 ratio between $\ce{[HO^-]}$ and $\ce{[H_3^+O]}$.

You also know that because $\ce{KOH}$ dissociates completely in water solution, $\ce{[HO^-]_{KOH}} = 1.0 \times 10^{-11} M$

Therefore, the *correct* way to solve this system would be using $\ce{K_{w}}$. Work below:

$\ce{K_{w}=\sum{[HO^-]\sum[H_3^+O]}}=1.0\times10^{-14}$

$\ce{=([HO^-]_{water}}+\ce{[HO^-]_{KOH})([H_3^+O]_{water})}$

Because $\ce{[HO^-]_{water} = [H_3^+O]_{water}}$, we can make this substitution:

Let $x=\ce{[HO^-]_{water} = [H_3^+O]_{water}}$

Therefore,

$\ce{=(x}+\ce{[HO^-]_{KOH})(x)} = 1.0\times10^{-14}$

And you can solve for x from here. Keep in mind what x equals!

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with the Latex markup here and had to keep refreshing to see the effects of my syntax.

Comment: You have a preview under your edit window, there you can see how your post will look like.

Comment: You should also use \times ($\times$) when you want to multiply terms.

Comment: I never noticed that it changed! You're right; I'll just scroll down next time to see my changes.

Comment: @LDC3 or even better `\cdot`($\cdot$) as $\times$ refers to a vector product

Comment: So you want me to edit it again ;)?

Comment: @Martin When there are 2 numbers, I'm sure nobody will mistake them for vectors (i.e. $2.4 \times 10^{-5}$).

Comment: @LDC3 I agree, that there will be no confusion, bit this should be no excuse to use the correct notation. The main principle behind the notation $\times$ is that a vector product does not necessarily commute, while a product of scalars does.

Comment: Glad it helped!